# Marketing Cloud Push Notification not received on Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I have implemented the Marketing Cloud SDK in an mobile application using the Marketing Cloud cordova plugin (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) and i have contacts being correctly registered in the Push channel.

THE PROBLEM IS:
I'm able to send notifications but the devices only receive the notification when the application is running (both in foreground and background). If we remove the application from the recent applications menu, the application no longer receives notifications. The SDK should be handling this situation. Can you please provide us with a solution for this? (This is an urgent problem)

Answer (score 4):

For most devices, removing the app from recents will have no effect on whether the app can receive a push message.  For some device models, I have seen that removing an app from recents is treated the same as force stopping the app.  This is an attempt by the manufacturer to gain better performance, usually as related to battery, on a low-end device.  This could also be a side-effect of the app launcher implementation of some 3rd party launchers.

For example, removing my app from recents on my Nexus 6P, Pixel 2 XL, Pixel 3 XL and emulators from Android Studio all receive any push notification that is sent to the app.  If I force stop the app on any of these devices I will no longer receive push messages until I have reopened the app.

Comment: If this is not a satisfactory answer then you can open a support ticket with your Salesforce representative so that more information can be exchanged to help you.

Comment: Hello @Seth, this seems not to be the case. The application only receives notifications if it is in foreground (if the application is running in background, or paused, it does not receive notifications).
We get the same result if we use the learning app provided for Android https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance, Samuel

Comment: Hello, we may face the same issue... Is there any solutions for that ?

Comment: Facing the same issue, Android not receiving notification in background using marketing cloud, but while sending from fcm it's working fine, we are using single push provider. iOS push notifications are working fine.